# Socket in node.js vs socket in Dart

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, dart

I've the below code working perfectly with Dart, interested to have similar one with NODE, using PURE NODE modules, as I'm interested to check the performance of my app in Dart if it was written in JavaScript in client and NODE in server.

I do not want to use any third party package like socket.js or whatever.

```
import 'dart:io';

 void main() { 
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 8080).then((HttpServer server) {
    print("HttpServer listening...");
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      if (WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request)){
          WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then(handleWebSocket);
       }
  else {
        print("Regular ${request.method} request for: ${request.uri.path}");
        serveRequest(request);
        }
    });
 });
}
```

any thought how to write same code in NODE, using PURE NODE modules without any third party module/package?

Comment: *Any thought* on what? What are you asking?

Comment: how to write same code in NODE, using PURE NODE modules without any third party module/package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way to create it with pure node, so I started using the [Faye npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faye) as a best module I found for using both web-socket and Server-Sent Event (SSE)